# Network data out - nmon/nload vs AWS Cloudwatch disparity

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, video-conferencing, network-monitoring

We are running a video conferencing server in an EC2 instance.

Since this is a data out (egress) heavy app, we want to monitor the network data out closely (since we are charged heavily for that).

[image]

As seen in the screenshot above, in our test, using **nmon** (top right) or **nload** (left) in our EC2 server shows the network out as **138 Mbits/s** in nload and **17263 KB/s** in nmon which are very close (138/8 = 17.25).

But, when we check the network out (bytes) in **AWS Cloudwatch** (bottom right), the number shown is very high **(~ 1 GB/s)** (which makes more sense for the test we are running), and this is the number for which we are finally charged.

Why is there such a big difference between nmon/nload and AWS Cloudwatch?
Are we missing some understanding here? Are we not looking at the AWS Cloudwatch metrics correctly?

Thank you for your help!

**Edit:**

Adding the screenshot of a longer test which shows the average network out metric in AWS Cloudwatch to be flat around 1 GB for the test duration while nmon shows average network out of 15816 KB/s.

[image]

Comment: The CW screenshot you showed is the average network out bytes in 5 minutes.

Comment: @jellycsc - But, in the screenshot it says -> Statistic: Average & Period: 1 second.

Comment: I know. Although you selected `1 second`, the data is not captured or pushed to CW at that frequency. You can kinda see in the CW graph that the data points are roughly 5 minutes apart.

Comment: Ok. Even if it's a 5 min average, I'm not sure how to make sense out of it when compared with nmon data. In our tests, we see the CW graph to be flat at 1 GB for the test duration (when we select the metrics - Statistic: Average & Period: 1 second) . But, nmon still shows average network out of around 15-18 MB/s.

Comment: @jellycsc - Added a screenshot showing the data for a longer test duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured out the answer to this.

The following link talks about the periods of data capture in AWS:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html

> **Periods**
>
> A period is the length of time associated with a specific
> Amazon CloudWatch statistic. Each statistic represents an aggregation
> of the metrics data collected for a specified period of time. Periods
> are defined in numbers of seconds, and valid values for period are 1,
> 5, 10, 30, or any multiple of 60. For example, to specify a period of
> six minutes, use 360 as the period value. You can adjust how the data
> is aggregated by varying the length of the period. A period can be as
> short as one second or as long as one day (86,400 seconds). The
> default value is 60 seconds.
>
> Only custom metrics that you define with a storage resolution of 1
> second support sub-minute periods. Even though the option to set a
> period below 60 is always available in the console, you should select
> a period that aligns to how the metric is stored. For more information
> about metrics that support sub-minute periods, see High-resolution
> metrics.

---

As seen in the link above, if we don't set a custom metric with custom periods, AWS by default does not capture sub-minute data. So, the lowest resolution of data available is every 1 minute.

So, in our case, the network out data within 60 seconds is aggregated and captured as a single data point.

Even if I change the statistic to *Average* and the period to *1 second*, it still shows every 1 minute data.

Now, if I divide 1.01 GB (shown by AWS) with 60, I get the per second data which is roughly around 16.8 MBps which is very close to the data shown by nmon or nload.

Answer (score 0):

From the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html):

> `NetworkOut`: The number of bytes sent out by the instance on all network interfaces. This metric identifies the volume of outgoing network traffic from a single instance.
> The number reported is the number of bytes sent during the period. If you are using basic (five-minute) monitoring, you can divide this number by 300 to find Bytes/second. If you have detailed (one-minute) monitoring, divide it by 60.

The `NetworkOut` graph in your case does not represent the current speed, it represents the number of bytes sent out by all network interfaces in the last 5 minutes. If my calculations are correct, we should get the following values:

```
1.01 GB ~= 1027 MB (reading from your graph)

To get the average speed for the last 5 minutes:

1027 MB / 300 = 3.42333 MB/s ~= 27.38 Mbits/s
```

It is still more than what you are expecting, although this is just an average for the last 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ervin. I had thought the same and did similar calculation but still found the Cloudwatch metric to be way off from what nmon or nload shows. nload shows around 100+ Mbits/s average for this test.